# Calling dispatchQueue.sync in deinit causes unowned reference of self

Tags: swift

In a class, I put all members read/write in a serial dispatchQueue to protect multi-thread access. But I got a fatal error of unowned reference to `self` when I pass `[unowned self]` to dispatchQueue's task in deinit.

In the following example, I can still read `self` and `refCount(self)` is still not 0 in `deinit{}` before calling `self.q.sync{...}`. Then fatal error raised immediately when passing `[unowned self]` to queue's task

#### Example

```
class Host {
  let text = "Hello"
  let q = DispatchQueue(label: "workingloop")
  deinit {
    // `self` is ok to be read
    print("begin count: \(CFGetRetainCount(self)), ptr: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())")

    self.q.sync { [unowned self] in // <- callstack stop here
      print(self.text)
    }

    // not reach
    print("end count: \(CFGetRetainCount(self)), ptr: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())")
  }
}

func foo() {
  let host = Host() 
  // <- trigger Host.deinit()
}
```

### Output

```
begin count: 2, ptr: 0x000000010871fb00
Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but object 0x10871fb00 was already deallocated 2020-01-13 10:31:11.758734+0800 xctest[29473:2710298] Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but object 0x10871fb00 was already deallocated
```

---

Is the `class.deinit{}` a special scope where we should not pass `self` to another thread or task?

I also try to pass using `[weak self]`, and the `self` is still a `nil`. Don't know why its reference count reached zero at another task.

Comment: How are you triggering Host.deinit() , Deinitializers cannot be accessed

Comment: When `host` variable is not referenced anymore, Host.deinit() will be triggered I thought. I am not directly calling deinit, I just let it out of foo() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What *is* `deinit`? It is when a reference type instance is being deallocated. *Why* is it being deallocated? Because its reference count reached 0. That is what reference count memory management *is*.

> Don't know why its reference count reached zero at another task.

I don't know what you mean by "at another task". Its reference count is zero in `deinit` by definition.

Comment: Thanks! I didn’t notice the deinit is called because variable reference count reached zero. It is already 0 reference count.